# Do enemies only drop food after beating the game?

Tags: river-city-girls

I've never seen enemies drop food until I started Loitering. Were those drops unlocked by beating the game / seeing the credits?

And is it only because I'm Loitering, instead of going to New Game +?

Comment: I haven't completed the game yet but I have seen them occasionally drop something edible.

Comment: @Shadur - What's your Luck stat? That might play a part in things!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, enemies can drop food before you beat the game. In the following playthrough you can see a defeated enemy drop an apple at 46:44 and a salad at 51:16.

[A tweet from Wayforward](https://twitter.com/WayForward/status/1172563127503900677?lang=en) says that your Luck stat affects how often enemies will drop food, so food would presumably be more likely to drop near the end of the game after you've leveled up.